# How do I remove these edges connected to the center?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edges

After using a boolean to create a hole in my mesh these edges started to connect to it. How can I remove the edges without also getting rid of the face?[image]

Comment: You could select them and press "X" > Edges only. That would leave you with an n-gon though (I guess it already is one).

Comment: @Dontwalk Blender can't Dissolve an Edge in such Geometry.It says "Invalid Foundry Region to join faces".

Comment: @ julian Sandoval - Sry didn't try it first (Works in other situations). You should still consider modeling it with Quad based Topology.